# Haskell language extensions: pragma vs. compiler flag?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

To use a language extension such as `UnicodeSyntax` in all files of a project, 2 options are:

- A pragma in every source file:
  `{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}`
- Adding `extensions: UnicodeSyntax` in every section (library, executable, test) of the `.cabal` file.

Are there any reasons or best practices to choose one over the other?

I'm using `stack` and their standard `new-template` for simple packages.

Comment: Note that you can be selective: for every source file, you can enable different extensions...

Comment: Furthermore: do you make use of a `Makefile`?

Comment: Agreed @CommuSoft, but if I use the extension in all files, the compiler flag seems to reduce duplication. I'm wondering if the compiler flag is some kind of bad practice though.

Comment: I don't see why given you include the flags in some `Makefile` or shell script, otherwise it will be hard for other programmers to "guess" the correct flags. Note that a potential advantage can be that an analysis program (like `fish` that can parse the `man` pages), could already warn if the flag is not available.

Comment: Since `my.cabal` contains: `ghc-options: «some options»` it does sound ghc-specific and not portable, as opposed to the pragma.

Comment: I personally use "extensions" (although I believe it's now been renamed to "default-extensions" in later cabals) in all my projects. stack definitely understands it, as does ghc-mod and haskell-mode and friends.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I always list all the language extensions in each file that uses them. Then you can tell exactly what extensions a particular piece of code is using, just by looking at the code. That means I can instantly tell, for example, is this code doing something with Template Haskell or not. And I don't have to look at any related files to figure that out. It also means I can compile just that module, manually from the command line, without having to memorise which extensions I need.

I suppose there is something to be said for being able to glance at the Cabal spec to see which extensions a particular package uses.

Comment: It would be nice to have a `required-extensions` section for cabal to make it fail/warn if a module requests an unlisted extension, and to warn if the build completes and a listed extension has never been requested.